# Spring WebSocket Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm new to Spring configurations, thus the question.

I have followed this tutorial and created a Web Scoket application which works fine on the Spring embedded server.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Now instead of using the embedded server I want o deploy it on a local instance of Tomcat. I have done the following,

```
Added facets to the project and made it dynamic web project in eclipse
Created the server in eclipse
```

Now when I deploy it, it opens up the index.html but the buttons dont work.
I think I need to configure the project for deploying on a local tomcat.
Can someone help me with that.

Comment: which version of tomcat did you use? check if websocket is supported by your tomcat.

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 8